# Sumar el contenido de una cadena con otra(en este caso números)

Tags: c

Tengo un problema, al momento de sumar números de una cadena con otra, en este caso solo estoy probando la suma, pues determine las cadenas con el mismo tamaño, el programa pide que digite los números a sumar y si los hace pero por ejemplo cuando son sumas que rebasan las 10 unidades pues hay que llevar un acarreo y no consigo cómo hacerlo.
les dejo el código...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 3

void add(char num1[],char num2[],char nadd[]);

int main()
{
    int i,j;
    char cad1[MAX];
    char cad2[MAX];
    char nadd[MAX];

    fflush(stdin);
    i=0; j=0;
    for (i=0;i<=MAX-1;i++)
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Digite un numero en cad1 posicion=%d: ",i);
        scanf("%d",&cad1[i]);
    }

    fflush(stdin);
    for(j=0;j<=MAX-1;j++)
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Digita un numero en cad2 posicion=%d: ",j);
        scanf("%d",&cad2[j]);
    }

    add(cad1,cad2,nadd);

    getch();
    return 0;
}

void add(char num1[],char num2[],char nadd[])
{
    int i;
    int suma;
    char recibe[MAX+1]; 

    i=0; 

    for(i=0;i<=MAX-1;i++)
    {
        recibe[i]=num1[i]+num2[i]; //suma del contenido de las cadenas pero cuando se tiene que llevar el acarreo no se cómo implementarlo...
        printf("\t%d",recibe[i]); 
    }
 }
```

Comment: Esperas que el usuario haga la entrada de datos dígito por dígito? Es decir, con una combinación Dígito + Enter?

Comment: Si tu pregunta fué resuelta te recomiendo señales la respuesta que creas resolvió tu pregunta. Para mas información consulta [aquí](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: si así es Marco Ramírez

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tendrás que añadir en tu función

```
void add(char num1[],char num2[],char nadd[])
```

la lógica que hará dicho acarreo.

```
void add(char num1[],char num2[])  /* no se está usando nadd */
{
    int i;
    char recibe[MAX+1] = {0}; 

    for(i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        recibe[i] = num1[i] + num2[i]; 

        if(recibe[i] >= 10)
        {
            /* Evitamos acceder a localidades no definidas por el arreglo */
            if(i < MAX - 1)
            {
                recibe[i+1]++;
            }

            recibe[i] -= 10;
        } 

        printf("\t%d",recibe[i]); 
    }
 }
```

Esta solución es asumiendo que cada dígito se introduce en una llamada a scanf separada. Es decir, cada localidad del arreglo de entrada contendrá un entero en el rango de [0, 9].

En este caso se agregó una lógica similar a la operación de suma en donde el acarreo se hace a la posición de orden mayor y se hace un ajuste (restamos 10) debido a dicho acarreo.